# Agox installation

Tags: algorithm, optimization, global

I have problem with installation of AGOX, prerequisites are

```
A C compiler (Tested with Intel/2018.1.163)

An MPI installation (Tested with openmpi/4.0.3)
```

how to install these on Ubuntu, kindly help me with this. Thank you.

I have tried installing agox on ubuntu using the documentation given on github but got an error saying
ERROR: Could not find a version that satisfies the requirement agox (from versions: none)
ERROR: No matching distribution found for agox